# Guice @Provides method doesn't work

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a method annotated with `@Provides` in my Guice config, but it doesn't work.

```
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

  ...

  @Provides @RequestScoped
  EntityManager provideEntityManger() {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  }

}
```

When I run my application I get the following error:

> com.google.inject.CreationException:
>   Guice creation errors:<|<|1) No
>   implementation for
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager was
>   bound.<|  while locating
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager<|
>   for parameter 0 at
>   com.someclass.of.myproject

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like a scoping related issue to me. Are you sure that the scoping is correct? When your webapp starts, it won't be in RequestScope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're using `@Provides` incorrectly. An `@Provides` method must be in one of the `Module`s that you use when initializing Guice... you can't just put it in the `GuiceServletContextListener`.